# Filling data in 2D dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, opencv

I want to store String type data variables in memory, these variables are actually hex code of image. So there will be a 2D dynamic array, which stores data on run-time.
I tried following code to fill data, first creating pointer to pointer dynamic array as shown below.

```
//dynamic allocation of array
int row = rows - 1;
int col = cols - 1;
Mat img = image;
cout << " row " << row << " col " << col <<endl;

    String **matrix;
    matrix= new String*[row]; // dynamic array (size 10) of pointers to int

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = new String[col];
        // each i-th pointer is now pointing to dynamic array (size 10) of actual int values
    }
```

Here, I got the memory on heap if I am not wrong. So I write nested loop to extract RGB information, convert into hex String and store in array.

```
for (int r = 0; r <= row; r++) {

        cout << endl;

        for (int c = 0; c <= col; c++)
        {

            Vec3b intensity = img.at<Vec3b>(r, c);

            uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
            int b = (int)blue;
            uchar green = intensity.val[1];
            int g = (int)green;
            uchar red = intensity.val[2];
            int r = (int)red;

            //filling dynamic array
            matrix[row][col] = RGBToHex(r,g,b);

        }

    }
```

Here is the method by which I am converting RGB to Hex String.

```
string RGBToHex(int rNum, int gNum, int bNum)
{
    // returns 6 digit hex code
    string result;
    char r[255];
    sprintf_s(r, "%.2X", rNum);
    result.append(r);
    char g[255];
    sprintf_s(g, "%.2X", gNum);
    result.append(g);
    char b[255];
    sprintf_s(b, "%.2X", bNum);
    result.append(b);
    return result;
}
```

I tried to extract RGB info, convert into Hex String, store in .txt file, it works but following exception is thrown when am trying to fill array.

Kindly highlight the problem and let me know where I am wrong.

```
 **Exception thrown at 0x000007FEE1AD7330 (opencv_world310.dll) in ImageDecoder.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

    If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int r = 0; r <= row; r++) {
```

I think it should be `r < row` instead of `r <=row`

If you have allocated 2D array of 10x10 then this `matrix[row][col]` should be `matrix[9][9]` and your loop make it `matrix[10][10`] which is a problem.

Also problem with below statement, use row instead of 10.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
```

Comment: It works fine, i printed Hex info into .txt file to test.

Comment: Plus indexing your matrix should be `matrix[r][c]` as those are the running variables. `matrix[row][col]` still causes overindexing.

Comment: int row = rows - 1;
int col = cols - 1; 
This is how i defined variables outside the loop.

Comment: Also you may want to change the name of variable `int r = (int)red;` which would otherwise hide row index variable `r`.

Comment: @winnetou yes, that r could be one more problem apart from index.

Comment: @RoshaanNayyar I see problem with your new code as well. You dynamically allocate memory for 9x9 now and trying to access 10th element.

Comment: @Digital_Reality, Problem solved i was trying to access 10th element. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> matrix[row][col] = RGBToHex(r,g,b);

The way you have defined `matrix`, at most you can access `matrix[row-1][col-1]`, isn't it?

Not saying that `row` and `col` seem to be fixed values.

Comment: int row = rows - 1;
int col = cols - 1;
I did it before loop.